# How to convert a C statement using malloc() to C++?

Tags: c++, c, memory-management, malloc

I have a buffer in C with this code

```
    buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*CACHE_LEN*2);
```

How can I change this line to C++?

Is it better with `malloc` or with `new[]`?
I cannot understand the meaning of this `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Answer (score 4):

The line you mention will compile fine in C++, save for that fact that if `buffer` is not a `void *`, then you may need to cast the return value of `malloc` in C++, which you don't need to do in C (and probably should not do).

EG:

```
uint32_t *buffer = (uint32_t *) malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*CACHE_LEN*2);
```

However, you may wish to convert to a `new` / `delete` paradigm; that will require more than just changing that line.

EG:

```
uint32_t *buffer = new uint32_t[CACHE_LEN*2];
...
delete[] buffer;
```

If you want to be more C++-like still, then use `std::vector` or similar:

```
std::vector<uint32_t> buffer(CACHE_LEN*2);
```

Comment: I thought that ```std::vector``` actually granted the C memory layout... Am I wrong?

Comment: @Paolo.Bolzoni really? I didn't know that. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Don't get confused by the title, read the whole thing: http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Comment: You learn a new thing every day. My C++ days were pre `std::vector`. I will amend.

Comment: When I need C functions for any reason (I used ```mkdir``` recently) I always use ```std::vector``` for the arrays. It is quite useful. In the C++11 you even get the ```.data()``` member function that returns the pointer to the first element. I like it more than the older ```& v.front()``` I had to use before.

Comment: @abligh where i need to put the delete code? in Destructor ?

Comment: If you have the need to put a ```new[]``` in the constructor and a ```delete[]``` in the destructor, by all means use a ```std::vector``` because that what it does.

Comment: @xmaze you'd put it exactly where you had the `free()` in C++, i.e. at the point you no longer need it. Whether or not that's in the object's destructor depends on whether it shares the same life-cycle as the object.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `CACHE_LEN` is indeed a macro that hides a value that is known at compile time:

```
auto buffer = make_unique<array<uint32_t, CACHE_LEN*2>>();
```

This has the fun property that you get pretty much all the advantages of modern C++ at just about zero overhead.

If you wish to stay somewhat closer to your C roots or `CACHE_LEN` is not known at compile time, you can alternatively use, which removes some features that `array` provides:

```
auto buffer = make_unique<uint32_t[]>(CACHE_LEN*2);
```

Finally, if you want to go all the other way, you can use a fully dynamic array (`vector` in C++ lingo):

```
auto buffer = std::vector<uint32_t>(CACHE_LEN*2);
```

All of the above solutions ensure that resource management is being done by the scope of `buffer`. The solutions that use `make_unique` can (more or less) easily be changed to use shared pointers instead.

To stay completely old-school, `std::malloc` and `std::free` exist in C++ as well, but `malloc` requires casting its result to the proper pointer type. They can also be replaced with `new uint32_t[CACHE_LEN*2]` and `delete[] buffer`.

P.S.:
The meaning of the `sizeof(uint32_t)` is simply to account for the fact that `malloc` does not allocate a number of elements, but rather a number of bytes - and most types require more than 1 byte per element.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::vector<uint32_t> v(CACHE_LEN * 2);
```

`sizeof(type)` return the size in chars of the type of the expression passed. For a `uint32_t` it would be 4.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::vector<uint32_t> v(CACHE_LEN*2)`?

Comment: My sleepiness... Fixed.

Comment: @MatsPetersson weird, I made the same error - edit borrowed :-)

Answer (score 1):

sizeof() gives the size in byte of the type given between the parenthesis. The type takes sizeof() in memory. This you need to know when you allocate memory to store data in. The `CACHE_LEN * 2` depends solely on your usage.

If you need to store five times a pair of uint32_t you use:

```
malloc( sizeof( uint32_t ) * 2 * 5 );
```

`malloc` will allocate a fixed size of memory. This means you can't change the size.

The new/delete is equivalent to malloc/free but in C++. If you use new[] you should use delete[] also.

```
char buf = new char[ 10 ];
delete[] buf;
```

The delete[] goes where the life cycle of the allocated memory has ended. If you create it within a function, then the delete[] should be there too. Or you get memory leaks. If you have it at the global scope of a class and you allocate the memory in the constructor, it is an assumption to delete[] the memory in the destructor but is usually the case. It depends on why and when you need the memory. One thing is for sure, if you allocate you need to deallocate (new[]/delete[]).

> Paolo Bolzoni mentioned the use of std::vector

That's perfectly fine and in most cases very easy to use. If you need to optimize your code for speed, having a fixed size memory block would be faster then a std::vector. It depends on your needs but also your preference.

Comment: *'`malloc` will allocate memory statically'* - given `malloc` is the main function for dynamic memory allocation, that's not the right terminology. Also you resize with `realloc` not `ralloc`. Moreover `realloc` does its own copying - you don't need to copy yourself.

Comment: ralloc is a typo. will edit it on the next edit. Am looking into it a bit, did needed to copy the memory but maybe I am wrong. But it is static, the memory block is fixed, can't grow nor shrink. Why isn't that static?

Comment: Didn't used realloc back in my earlier days of c++. Sorry for my confusion.

Comment: Failed to defend my terminology.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> buffer = malloc(sizeof(uint32_t)*CACHE_LEN*2);
> ```

This can be *"translated"* in C++ in several ways.

But, first it must be clear what this does in C, since you wrote in your question that it's not clear for you the meaning of `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

Using `malloc()`, you can dynamically (i.e. at *run-time*) allocate some **contiguous** space from the *heap*.
The parameter you pass to `malloc` is the *size* of the requested space, **in bytes**.
The code you posted seems to allocate `CACHE_LEN*2` count of `uint32_t` elements. Since `malloc` expects its size parameter to be measured *in bytes*, you have to multiply `CACHE_LEN*2` (the *"count"* factor) by the size, in bytes, of each element, i.e. of a `uint32_t`, which is `sizeof(uint32_t)`.

So, you have:

- element type: `uint32_t`
- element count: `CACHE_LEN*2`
- size of each element, in bytes: `sizeof(uint32_t)`

So:

> *Total size in bytes* for `malloc()` = `sizeof(uint32_t) * CACHE_LEN*2`

Now that this `malloc()` call should be clear, let's move forward to the C++ equivalent.

---

The most immediate "mapping" is from C's `malloc()` to C++'s **`new[]`**.

Note that, while `malloc` requires the size to be expressed in *bytes*, when you call `new[]` you can just specify the **element count** (*not* the *raw* byte count).

So, a C++ code using `new[]` would be something like this:

```
// Allocate (CACHE_LEN*2) elements of type uint32_t
uint32_t* buffer = new uint32_t[CACHE_LEN*2];
```

When you allocate memory using `malloc()`, you have to free it using `free()`.
The C++ counterpart of `new[]` is **`delete[]`**, e.g.:

```
// Release buffer memory allocated with new[]
delete[] buffer;

// Avoid dangling references
buffer = nullptr;
```

But there's more. When **memory allocation fails**, `malloc` just returns `NULL`. Instead, C++'s `new[]` **throws an exception** in case of allocation failure. This exception is of type `std::bad_alloc`. You can catch that somewhare in your code to handle the memory allocation failure case.

If you want a behavior similar to `malloc`, with failed allocations returning a `nullptr` pointer, you can use the **`std::nothrow`** constant with `new[]`, e.g.:

```
buffer = new (std::nothrow) uint32_t[CACHE_LEN*2];
// On allocation failure, just returns nullptr
// (does *not* throw an exception).
```

---

However, in *modern C++* code, you may want to use a convenient container class to store your contiguous buffer memory. A very common candidate for that is **`std::vector`**.

`std::vector` is a class template: you specify the type of the elements as template argument, and you can specify the element count as a constructor parameter, e.g.:

```
#include <vector>  // For std::vector 
....

std::vector<uint32_t> buffer(CACHE_LEN*2);
```

Since the default memory allocator for `vector` uses `new[]` for allocating memory, in case of allocation failure the above constructor will throw a `std::bad_alloc` C++ exception.

Note that the memory allocated by a `vector` is **automatically** released by the vector's *destructor*. So you don't have to manually release that memory. This helps writing code that is *structurally incapable of leaking memory* (and other resources).

You can access the items in the vector using its overloaded `operator[]`, just like an ordinary simple raw array (e.g. `buffer[i]` accesses the i-th item in the buffer; note that indexes are `0`-based).

If you want a pointer to the beginning of the vector (which is the strict equivalent of your `buffer` pointer), you can call `vector`'s **data()** method, e.g.:

```
// Points to the beginning of vector memory
uint32_t* ptr = buffer.data();
// ...use ptr...
```

Answer (score 0):

With `C++`, `malloc` become `new`/`new[]` and `free` become `delete`/`delete[]`.

Comment: The OP creates an array. Simply replacing his `malloc` and `free` with `new` and `delete` would be disastrous.

Comment: Can you explain me why ? I am a beginner in C++