# How to use correctly the malloc() return value in if statement?

Tags: c++, malloc

I want to use an `if` statment with the `malloc()` function.
I have this code:

```
if(uint16_t *buf = (uint16_t *) malloc(data_len*2) == NULL) exit(1);
```

But I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert 'bool' to 'uint16_t*' in assignment
```

Am I wrong or I have to change the code?

This is the original code with brackets and etc:

`if ((data = malloc(data_len)) == NULL ||
        (buf = malloc(data_len*2)) == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }`

Comment: First, decide for a programming language. The code you mention is bad in either, but for different reasons. That said, the error is caused by the order in which the various operators are evaluated, it's not what you want.

Comment: Add a pair of brackets `if((uint16_t *buf = (uint16_t *) malloc(data_len*2)) == NULL)`

Comment: As been said, you don't need malloc() in C++. That is a C thing.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt the original C code whas this one, buf = malloc(data_len*2)== NULL and i asked the community http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28226016/how-to-convert-a-c-statement-using-malloc-to-c how to do that in C++.

Comment: Use a std::vector<uint16_t> then. It will signal allocation failure using exceptions, so you don't clutter your code with useless checks. That said, you should have used static_cast in C++, but the other comments are right, don't use malloc() there in the first place. BTW: Consider the scope of `buf` in your version!

Comment: @WeatherVane brackets are ok.

Comment: As others have commented, the extra bracket pair is to override the operator precedence - see the answer from @juanchopanza, and your edited question contains examples which have the brackets correctly, that is, they assign the pointer from `malloc()` *before* testing for `NULL`.

Comment: You could also optimize the code to `if (malloc(data_len * 2) == NULL) exit(1);`, which is basically the same. It also saves the occasional reader much pondering what that is supposed to do, it's obvious that it makes no sense then.

Comment: @WeatherVane i edited my question and i posted the whole of code, i still think that brackets are ok!

Comment: Perhaps you do, but read the very first comment, add some brackets, and see if the compiler error goes away!

Answer (score 3):

The problem is *operator precedence*, and applies to both C and C++. The equality operator `==` has higher precedence than assignment `=`, so your condition expression is parsed as

```
uint16_t *buf = ( (uint16_t *) malloc(data_len*2) == NULL)
```

with an `uint16_i*` on the LHS and a `bool` on the RHS. It seems what you wanted was

```
(uint16_t *buf = (uint16_t *) malloc(data_len*2)) == NULL
```

As an aside, note that there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` in C (since the question was tagged C).

And in C++, you should seriously consider using an `std::vector<uint16_t>` to avoid manual memory allocation.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `malloc()` in C++, use `new [type]` instead where [type] is the type your allocating.

Also, use class types whenever possible as that will save you a lot of memory management.

As the other answer stated, you should remember that assignment operators have a lot lower precedence than most other operators; use `()` to force precedence and it is recommended you do **not** do assignment in conditinals, it makes code messy.

Note: While you could use `malloc` in this case, `new` is generally preferred in most cases because `new` calls a class's constructor if there is one. The main reason to use `malloc` in C++ code is if you want to change the size of the allocated memory with `realloc`. These functions are part of the original C library and have been superceded by C++ more type safe operators and are therefore discouraged.

Comment: And how would `new` fix the problem?

Comment: Take the `std::string` class for instance -- it saves you the pain of allocating data  manually and is dynamic too. I'll change it to say memory management though.

Comment: If he's using C++, new calls the constructors; malloc is a C function

Comment: @Isaiah advice to use `new` is O.K., but if OP needs to use `malloc()` or is just curious what's wrong, then your answer does not anwer the question.

Comment: And how would calling the non-existent constructors of `uint16_t` help OP with their compiler error?

Comment: I fixed it to answer the question.